# Registering to onchange event for razor @Html.HiddenFor

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am using asp.net mvc 4, jquery and razor. I have below razor statemet in my view:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.MyItemViewModel.id);
```

I need to call a jquery/javascript function when its value changes. So I have thought to suscribe jquery/javascript function to onchange event for HiddenFor razor tag but I do not know if it is possible.

I have implemented below code but it seems to not work as OnHiddenValueChanged is not reached:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ItemCompViewModel.id, new { onchange="OnHiddenValueChanged" });

<script>
    function OnHiddenValueChanged() {
    }
</script>
```

Or even better, how to detect from view when m.ItemCompViewModel.id (the item for my view model) has changed and then call the jquery/javascript function?

Any ideas?

Comment: A change event is never fired for a `hidden` element...?

Comment: Will ever **change** (at run-time in the client side) the value of an hidden field?!

Comment: I think this is the key: _"The change event is fired... when a change to the element's value **is committed by the user**."_ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/change

Comment: Depending on the condition I change this value to distinguish between two mode: edit or not edit. So in edit mode this value is set to > 0, otherwise it is set to 0. So I would like to know if there is some method to detect where this value changes and call then a jquery or javascript function.

Comment: How is the value being changed? Logically, it's being changed by javascript, so call whatever you need to when the existing javascript changes the value.

Comment: @JasonP This value is changed from the controller through the view model associated. So as far as I know I cannot call a jquery/javascript function from the controller.

Comment: So.. is the page refreshing, like from a postback? Because javascript event handlers don't persist between refreshes. You should be able to use javascript to check the value of the hidden field on page load and do what you need to.

Comment: Yes, the page after setting this value is refreshed (reloaded) and then after refreshing the hidden field has the value I want. My problem is how to detect this value has changed and then do some stuff. Well, I mean, the value for the field (id) of the view model is updated correctly, maybe it would be better registering to the on value changed in the field id of the view model. But how to do this? See my updated post.

Comment: If you need to know when the value _changes_, you could set a cookie before the postback and check on page load. If you just need to know what the value currently is, check the value on page load. However, should your "edit" functionality be a different controller action, like `controller/view/id` and `controller/edit/id`?

Comment: @JasonP From the scratch:I have a jqgrid and one of its columns is a link that allow to edit the row. On click on edit, an action in a controller is thrown. Then from that action i receive the id for that item being edited and from this id I retrieve the data I need to read from this item in the database. Once I obtain the corresponding data, I put them into the fields in the view in order the user can modify it.In the controller,I set the value for the hidden field, that is,the id of the item being edited(that corresponds to the id in the DB)so with this id I know what item is being modified.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are attempting to subscribe to the `onchange` client side function for a value that is generated on the server and changes only on the server. So it's normal that this client side function is never triggered. Actually you never used any javascript to change the value of the hidden field so you cannot expect this callback to be raised.

If you are modifying the value on the server, then it's up to the server to tell the client that the value changed. For example you could have some additional property on your view model telling that the value has changed (whatever that means in your context - because *changed* .must always be compared to some previous state). Then on the client you could serialize this property as a javascript variable so that the client side knows about the change that occured on the server.

Comment: Well, in fact, I have the "id" field in "MyItemViewModel" view model to know if it has changed or not which is associated to the hidden field. Could you post a piece of code on how to do what you have described? I am new on it... sorry.

Comment: I am wondering if it is possible to trigger manually from the controller the change event on hidden field in the view... Is it possible?

Comment: No, it's not possible. Controller code runs on the server, whereas javascript runs on the client.